# how do i put domain in front of AWS ESB

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, tomcat, dns

I asked a similar question another time, but might have been unclear.

I have a web service (tomcat 8) running on Amazon Elastic beanstalk and it is working fine. Then I have website running on **DomainA.com** which uses my aws tomcat for CRUD operations to data. Similarly I have an android app and an IPhone which both use the same aws tomcat and that is also working fine.

Now, I also own **DomainB** and I would like for my website and 2 different apps to call **DomainB** which then behind the scenes calls AWS. I want to do this because I might change cloud provider or I might upgrade my amazon server, both of which would probably result in new fqdn's - which would mean I would have to update all three applications. In case all three points to **DomainB** I would only have to update the pointer of **DomainB** to the new server and my three applications would not notice any change.

I tried setting up a web alias on One.com and it sort of works except I am not getting back the json I was expecting, but instead an iframe. In Postman I can see it says.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DomainB</title>
        <style type="text/css">
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
iframe {
display: block;
border: none;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="DomainA/path">
            <p>Your user agent does not support iframes. However you may visit 
                <a href="DomainA/path">the page that was supposed to be here</a>
            </p>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need both AWS services ELB and Route 53:

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/ https://aws.amazon.com/route53/

Comment: This might work if I only want to use AWS, but if I need some other third party wervice and want to use it via. DomainB then I still have the problem